# Translation an orthogonal transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, rigid-transformation

Translation is when we move an object in an $n$-dimensional space, to 
another point in the same space. It can be used to remove the mean of data points from a dataset. Mathematically we can define by a transformation matrix equation as follows:

If we have a dataset $\mathbf{A}$, with $m$ rows (instances), and $n$ columns (features), then we mean centre it:

$$
\mathbf{A}_{mc}= \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{W}_{mc}.
$$
The translation matrix is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dotsb & \dotsb & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \dotsb & \dotsb & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\
- \mu_1 & - \mu_2 & \dotsb & \dotsb & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So now is it an orthogonal transformation or not ? I think, it is not an orthognoal transformation since the translation matrix is not orthogonal, but I am not sure, could some one clarify this ?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an orthogonal transformation of $A$ is multiplication of $A$ by an orthogonal matrix, and nothing else. You have (cleverly) included an additive term alongside $A$. That disqualifies the map from being orthogonal.

Translation is an *isometry* of Euclidean space (see: [Euclidean group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group)). These are precisely the maps of the form $x\mapsto Mx+b$ where $M$ is an orthogonal matrix and $b$ is any vector. Translation is a special isometry, with $M$ being the identity map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that clarified it completely..!